# how to implement a sort_order for many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

I have a course to modules many-to-many relationship, A course can contain any number of modules and modules can be in any number of courses:

Tables

### Course

id
name

### rel_course_to_module

course_id
module_id

### module

id
name

How do I implement a course specific module sort_odering so a module within one course appears first and in another, it appears last? I am using Spring JPA with Hibernate,

Answer (score 0):

You can you spring data jpa with hibernate.

You can follow this documentation: [spring data jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts). Course and Module  Entity relation will be **many-to-many** relation.

here you can create a interface for repository and from this interface you can find Module by courseId

your code will be like this

```
public interface CourseDAO extends JpaRepository<Course, Integer> {
    public List<Course> findByIdOrderByNameAsc();
}
```

Here inside Course Entity you have to declare **List modules**. Here is a good example like your problem.

And for last part that you ask : You can create a priority column to your mapping table and implement your business logic that you want.

Comment: Hi flopcoder, thanks for your reply, I have done the rest,and I was not pretty sure about the last part, which is the priority or order column and how to map it in the business logic is in question.

Comment: found what I was looking for in here https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example

Comment: I also said that to you. to add a priority column to mapping table. :)